# Internal Server Error with a long executing PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, internal-server-error, simplepie, ini-set

I have one large PHP script, which is built up of separate sections:

- RSS feed fetching (SimplePie)
- storing items in MySQL DB
- check item content for images (checking for img tags with DOMDocument())
- generating crops from each image found (using PHP Image Magician)

Each section takes around 10-20 MB of server RAM. I checked this using:

```
echo memory_get_usage(true);
```

My server has a RAM of 300 MB, and just to be sure, I manually set the max_execution_time to 300 for long execution time and bumped up any memory limit just in case.

I have verified the memory limit and execution time with:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
echo ini_get('max_execution_time');
echo ini_get('memory_limit');
```

However, still, after about 90-120 seconds, the script just stops and I get an Internal Server Error message.

Where exactly is my problem ?

Comment: what does your error log say?

Comment: try to increase `more max_execution_time` and use `ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: You could try `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` see if you get the same result.

Comment: Apache has its own settings, in addition to PHP, that may need to also be adjusted.

Comment: Only one file ? Don't know how the architecture is but maybe `unset()` some values to release memory.

Comment: Like allways, the log message is the most important hint. What exactly does it say. If you didnt get a message, fix this first.